# Json Array into Simple Json

Tags: php, json, laravel

i have that json data

```
{"@attributes":{"titleID":"24151"},"artist":"ALMKLAUSI & SPECKTAKEL","title":"Mama Laudaaa","label":"Xtreme Sound"}
```

but i need that data like that

```
{titleID":"24151","artist":"ALMKLAUSI & SPECKTAKEL","title":"Mama Laudaaa","label":"Xtreme Sound"}
```

Comment: Good for you, have you tried anything?

Comment: yes , i did try , but nothing worked for me , so i'm here. may be any one can help me.

Comment: maybe share what u've done so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `foreach` loop for get this output.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$str ='{"@attributes":{"titleID":"24151"},"artist":"ALMKLAUSI & SPECKTAKEL","title":"Mama Laudaaa","label":"Xtreme Sound"}';
$arr = json_decode($str,true);
$final_arr= array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    if($key== '@attributes'){
        $key = key($value);
        $value= $value[key($value)];
    }
    $final_arr[$key]= $value;
}
$final_str = json_encode($final_arr);
print_r($final_str);
exit;
```

**Output:**

```
{"titleID":"24151","artist":"ALMKLAUSI & SPECKTAKEL","title":"Mama Laudaaa","label":"Xtreme Sound"}
```

Comment: please can you help me , if we have same thing in jquery.
actually im new and working on laravel api.

Comment: success: function(data) {
                        

                        var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item[autoType],
                                value: item[autoType],
                                data : item
                            }
                        });
                        // console.log(array);
                        response(array)
                    }